# Why does my nikon flash fire 3 short flashes before the full flash goes off?

Tags: nikon, flash

I have a Nikon D200 and I'm using the SB 800 flash.
I've been using this flash for a year and now when I take a shot the flash pops 3 short flashes and then the shutter engages and the full flash goes off. The batteries are OK.
Does anybody have any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Have you inadvertently activated the red eye reduction?

Comment: Also sounds like the CLS commander mode which I use quite a lot. What are your flash settings on the camera?

Comment: I did a reset on the camera and now the flash seems to be working properly. Thanks

Comment: I did a reset of the camera and it worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my D750. It took me ages to realise the red eye flash option was selected.

Answer (score 1):

If the ambient light is too low for the focus sensor to determine the focus, it will perform one or more low level flashes to get enough signal to test/adjust the focus. This would not happen if there is enough light, even if the flash is used for filler.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have inadvertently set the flash to either CLS commander mode or i-TTL Balanced Fill Flash. For Commander mode, check custom setting e3.

Answer (score -2):

On the D610, there is a flash "Modeling" option (on by default) that fires pre-flashes so you can supposedly see where flash shadows will fall - and make changes if needed. I've turned it off as it seems very impractical when taking hand-held photos. Guess it'd be useful with tripod and in studios.

Comment: The modeling option is usually a fast pulsing in order to simulate continuous light, but on separate command, not directly when you take a photo. I think it's unrelated to that.